# How to ignore file when working with Ansible's hosts alternative directory layout?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using the alternative directory layout as recommended in the 
[official documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout).

My directory structure is very simple. It looks like this:

```
 inventories
    └── dev
        └── hosts
```

The hosts file content is the following :

```
[mygroup]
myhost ansible_host=1.2.3.4
```

That's work very well.

But, I'm working with four virtuals machines and I don't want to keep a hosts file in my git repository. For documentation purpose and to keep track of the structure of this such file. I want to create a "template file" though the following structure.

```
inventories
    └── dev
        ├── hosts
        └── hosts.tpl
```

For example this tpl file have the following content:

```
[mygroup] myotherhost ansible_host=4.3.2.1
```

If execute a ansible command like this one :

```
ansible mygroup -i inventories/dev/ -m shell -a ls
```

The result I've got is the following :

```
myhost | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Operation timed out\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
myotherhost | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 4.3.2.1 port 22: Operation timed out\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

We've got an error message for hosts defined in inventories/dev/hosts  and inventories/dev/hosts.tpl.

I don't want Ansible to read my inventories/dev/hosts.tpl file, how to do that ?

ps : it's ok if I have to change the filename

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : I directly call the inventory file inventories/dev/hosts

`ansible -i inventories/dev/hosts -m shell -a ls`

It works well even with `group_vars` subdir.

Answer (score -1):

Try input the host name `myhost` instead of group name `mygroup` in your `ansible` command as below

```
ansible myhost -i inventories/dev/ -m shell -a ls
```